# Twilio Twimlets are broken

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

The echo twimlet gives this error in the developer console when trying to save:

```
TypeError: $(...) is null
 base.js:2:20968
TypeError: t is not a function
Ajax.Request<.initialize()
 ext.js:1
t()
 ext.js:1
Ext.lib.Ajax.request()
 ext.js:4
.request()
 ext.js:6
.save()
 twimlets.js:1
Ext.Button<.onClick()
 ext.js:13
E/a()
 ext.js:5
n/a()
 ext.js:3
 ext.js:1:18861
```

Any ideas on what might be the problem? I've tried even a very simple echo twimlet, as well as trying to edit an existing twimlet.

Comment: That does look broken! It's probably best to get in touch with [Twilio support](http://twilio.com/help/contact) who can direct this to the right team to investigate and hopefully fix.

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by saving the twimlet? It just generates a URL. I was just able to generate [this echo response URL](http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHello%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E&
).

Comment: @philnash The Twimlets service has the ability to save a twimlet as a short url that does a 302 redirect to the twimlet. (https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/my) This makes it easy to use in TWIML apps, edit them later, etc, but editing of an existing saved twimlet, or saving a new twimlet is broken now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently an issue with editing saved Twimlets. An error will occur when you attempt to edit a saved Twimlet. However, this error does not apply when generating a new Twimlet.

We are moving towards using [Twiml Bins](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/twiml-bins) in the Twilio Console. You can create request URLs containing some [TwiML instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) and save and edit them at anytime.

It can be a bit of extra work to do this from scratch so if you are really hoping to stick with the Twimlet, alternatively, be sure to check your URL encoding.

Comment: Thanks @megan-speir, I was able to properly urlencode the TWIML  in the echo twimlet and use it in the webhook field for my number. I also moved my other static twimlets over to TWIMLBins